# Carrousell SwipperJS Styling

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to reproduce the image example, at the end of the carousel the last 3 items contain opacity, but the opacity is fixed regardless of scrolling. any suggestion will be welcome

[image]

Comment: Could you please provide the code for this so that I can better understand the question?

Comment: Do you just whack a div on top with a semi-transparent gradient background on it, plus set `pointer-events: none` on it so that it doesn't eat all the mouse clicks? See: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/pointer-events/